# Checking if OLEDB returned a result from SELECT statement (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

In my .NET application I have to get results from a MS Access database. I would like to add error checking to make sure a row was returned from my SELECT statement.

How can I make sure a result was returned?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a little code to your question?

Comment: It depends on what you are using for the data access - ADO.NET?

Comment: Are there ADO.NET drivers for "Access"?

Comment: @David W. Fenton: assuming OLE DB then the 'driver', more correctly an OLE DB provider, would be Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.n.m or Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.n.m (n and m being major and minor version numbers respectively pertaining to the version of the Access Database Engine). While you can use the MSDASQL.1 provider with one of the Access ODBC drivers, this is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim mySelectCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM SomeTable") 
Dim myReader As OleDbDataReader = mySelectCommand.ExecuteReader()

If Not myReader.HasRows Then
    'No row has been returned'
End If
```